# Unusual behavior with std::vector

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, vector, stl

I've written a rather complicated set of classes to deal with iterating over a stream (string, file or memory). These are NOT std streams nor are they related. Anyway, due to iterating over these buffers and performing actions depending on the buffer, I want to be able to see the current buffer position in the debugger. So, for debug reasons only, I copy the whole stream to a vector and hold a pointer to a position in this vector.

The following code acts like a forward iterator. I need to be able to store a position and later either use it or update it. Please note, this code is only to duplicate the problem.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo ( std::string szTemp )
        : nOffset( 0 )
    {
        vec.resize( szTemp.size() );
        std::memcpy( &vec[ 0 ], szTemp.c_str(), szTemp.size() );
        pChar = &vec[ 0 ];
    }
    foo( const foo & Other )
        : vec( Other.vec )
        , nOffset( Other.nOffset )
    {
        pChar = &vec[ nOffset ];
    }

    void Inc ( void )
    {
        ++nOffset;
        pChar = &vec[ nOffset ];
    }

    size_t nOffset;
    char * pChar;
    std::vector< char > vec;
};

int _tmain ( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    foo a( "This is a temp string" );

    a.Inc();
    {
        foo b = a;
        b.Inc();
        a = b;
    } // Here is where the problem is seen
    a.Inc();
}
```

Problem, after copying b back to a then stepping out, the value of b.pChar becomes illegal.

As I understand it, b copies the vector from a, then a in turn copies it back from b. Since I set the value of pChar after this copy, it 'should' always point to something. But, it's acting like the vector is being destroyed.

What's going on?

Comment: "I've written a rather complicated set of classes to deal with iterating over a stream. [...] These are NOT std streams." <-- **that** is your problem.

Comment: Without knowing what I'm coding and what platform is targeted, that is an unfair comment. For your information I'm iterating over streams of unknown encoding. If you can point me to an stl stream class that can detect and convert to a common encoding then I'll eat my hat, until then, writing my own "wrappers" is what's required. Under the hood I use an ifstream to deal with the files, but that is not relevant to the posted problem.

Comment: Maybe Boost.Iostreams could help you to facilitate the cretion of own stream-like classes.

Comment: @Waldermort Without you explaining your exact task, this may very well be an XY problem, so it's unfair of you to expect **me** to **guess** what your real problem is.

Comment: I've already looked into it and decided the cons outweigh the pros in this project. The real object of the code is to deal with the underlying encodings.

Comment: @Waldermort What the hell are you even talking about? Lack of basic English skills? I don't even...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
    foo b = a;
    b.Inc();
    a = b;
} // Here is where the problem is seen
```

Your problem is here.

```
a = b;
```

request a call to assignment operator, that you are don't implement, so, default one will do memberwise-assignment. After this, your `char pointer` will be dangling pointer. Following code will do correct work.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo ( std::string szTemp )
        : nOffset( 0 )
    {
        vec.resize( szTemp.size() );
        std::memcpy( &vec[ 0 ], szTemp.c_str(), szTemp.size() );
        pChar = &vec[ 0 ];
    }
    foo( const foo & Other )
        : vec( Other.vec )
        , nOffset( Other.nOffset )
    {
        pChar = &vec[ nOffset ];
    }
    foo& operator = (const foo& other)
    {
       foo tmp(other);
       swap(tmp);
       return *this;
    }

    void Inc ( void )
    {
        ++nOffset;
        pChar = &vec[ nOffset ];
    }

    void Swap(foo& other)
    {
       std::swap(vec, other.vec);
       std::swap(nOffset, other.nOffset);
       std::swap(pChar, other.pChar);
    }

    size_t nOffset;
    char * pChar;
    std::vector< char > vec;
};
```

Comment: @Waldermort if you make `pChar` a function, there is no need for any of the special members, see my answer :-)

Comment: pChar is only a convenience so I can see what nOffset is actually pointing to while stepping through the code. Making it a function would over complicate it. On a side note, shouldn't the default copy operator also call std::vector's implementation?

Comment: @Waldermort Yes, it does call the `std::vector` copy ctor, that's not the problem. The problem is that it copies `pChar` as is, so `a.pChar` will point into `b.vec`. And `b` goes out of scope immediately after.

Comment: @Waldermort that convenience is the only thing making the default generated `op=` doing the wrong thing. Making it a function would make it even *less* complicated: **1** the function would be a very simple one-liner, so no more complication there, **2** you would not need to write `operator=` and **3** you would not need to update `pChar` every time you update `nOffset`. The latter is the most important, because chances are, that you some time *will* forget the simultaneous update, introducing a subtle bug or misleading debugging information.

Answer (score 3):

Your class doesn't follow the **rule of three**. You have a custom copy constructor, but not a custom assignment operator (and no custom destructor, but this particular class probably doesn't need it). Which means `foo b = a;` does what you want (calls your copy ctor), but `a = b;` does not (calls the default assignment op).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other two answers, aftert he assignment `a = b`, `a.pChar` points into `b.vec`, and since `b` has left scope, it is a dangling pointer. 
You should either obey the rule of three (rule of five with C++11's move operations), or make that rule unnecessary by avoiding the storage of `pChar`, since that seems to be just a convenience alias for `offset`:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo ( std::string szTemp )
        : nOffset( 0 )
    {
        vec.resize( szTemp.size() );
        std::coyp( begin(szTemp), end(szTemp), begin(vec) );
    }

    //special members:
    foo(foo const&)            = default;
    foo(foo&&)                 = default;
    foo& operator=(foo const&) = default;
    foo& operator=(foo&&)      = default;
    ~foo()                     = default;

    void Inc ( void )
    {
        ++nOffset;
    }

    char* pChar() //function instead of member variable!
    {
        return &vec[nOffset];
    }

    size_t nOffset;
    std::vector< char > vec;
};
```

This way, `pChar()` will always be consistent with `nOffset`, and the special members can be just defaulted (or omitted completely).